# Hiding Regex elements

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to parse out a value from a list of key value pairs. All data is dirty, as is mine. Key/vales can be separated by 1 or more spaces and values can contain spaces.  My data looks something like this:

```
@"cat=test desc=my dog has fleas     det=3  extra=example"
```

This has caused me to go to extremes to parse.  I almost have it with the following:

```
@"(?<=\bdesc\b\=)[\w\s:#/%\?:\-.]*((?:(\s*).*\=)|$)"
```

Only, the following key ("det=") is not being hidden. I've also tried it with ?> and ?< to no avail.  Help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to extract all key/value pairs. If you only want to extract one (or several) key/value pair(s), you only need to change the subpattern in the first capturing group with something more explicit (in this case don't forget to use word boundaries or something else that can act as):

```
([^\s=]+)=(\S+(?>\s+[^\s=]+)*(?!=))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6bD0/1)

details of `\S+(?>\s+[^\s=]+)*(?!=)`

```
\S+          # all that is not a whitespace
(?>          # open an atomic group
    \s+      # one or more whitespaces
    [^\s=]+  # all non-whitespaces characters except "="
)*           # repeat the atomic group zero or more times
(?!=)        # check if not followed by an "="
```

The pattern is designed to reduce the number of steps. The goal of the atomic group is to forbid backtracking for the subpattern `\s+[^\s=]+`, consequence, the only backtracking positions recorded by the regex engine are the starts of the group. When the equal sign is reached, `(?!=)` fails and only one backtracking step is needed (to return to the position before the last repetition).

Note that this pattern trims the trailing spaces for the value.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
/([^=]+)=([^=]+?)(?=\w+=|$)/g
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vJ3pW8/1). The key is using *lazy* modifier to match the value substring (in combination with a lookahead for a next property's name). If you don't want the trailing whitespace, use a slightly different [version](https://regex101.com/r/mE1cH9/1), based on the same approach:

```
/(\S+)=([^=]+?)(?=\s+\w+=|$)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which is rather useful (worth sharing).

Given the string @"cat=test desc=my dog has fleas     det=3  extra=example"

?<=\bdesc=)((?:(?!\s+\w+=).)+*

will give you "my dog has fleas."  The great part is that it allows spaces in the result (doesn't stop after "my").  It keeps pulling data until it hits "something=."  This regex also handles the first and last element cases.